# How do you keep slower units moving behind faster units while keeping them from getting separated?

Tags: starcraft-2

This especially comes into play for me with roach/hydra and to a lesser extent with ling/roach.  I want my roaches in front of the hydras to absorb damage, but since roaches (with speed) are faster than hydras they just get separated unless I spending some time microing their movement.

With zlot/stalkers the stalkers are faster and I want them in back so I just have the stalkers on follow on the zlots and just move the zlots and they'll stick together in the right formation.  I do the same thing with ling/roach even though it's not completely optimal but the speedlings will get into the fray fast enough that it's not a huge deal.

Comment: It's a feature in the next expansion, Heart of the Swarm, along with various features such as additional single player missions 1-3 new units for $50. For another $50 for the last expansion, you get more features such as a new and improved, pathing algorithm that finally does not suck. And you also get 1-3 new units. But wait there's more. For a measly $10, you get a DLC to add 2 new units.

Comment: I myself usually set the "faster" unit to "follow" the "slower" unit. Only do this when your 100% sure where the enemy is. You can easily get stomped if your not ready with all your units clumped up. The good thing is, that half you army whont engage without the rest!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your units meet up and wait for each other at various points along the way during your push, especially right before the attack so you can get in position. You just have to keep them together and tell them exactly where you want them to go. Xel'naga towers are good spots to rendezvous on your way over to the enemy as during that time period you get some extra vision which has saved me countless times when the enemy was also pushing as I was able to see them first and run my faster units back to my slower ones to intercept the enemy as a group. Even with all units of the same speed sending them straight into the enemy base in a line is going to cause trouble, you want to keep them all together.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike in Blizzard's last RTS, Warcraft 3, there is no way to have your army move in "formation" with the whole group moving at the speed of the slowest unit.

It sounds like you're already trying to get around this with Micro -- which is exactly the answer to your question, unfortunately. There's no way around it.

It may help to group your different speed units into seperate control groups, however, such that you can command them individually to stop, retreat, etc.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of but I was hoping someone might have a clever trick.  I do already group them separately, but it does sometimes backfire when I forget to move a group.